# Laravel5.1 Route set all URL to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I think get/post visit Controller

```
Route::match(['get','post']. '{Controller}/{method}','$Controller\$Controller_Controller@$method');
```

But this is error;

How to I localhos/website/User/login ,go to find Controllers/User/User_Controller@login?

Comment: Your Question is unclear. Please elaborate it.

Comment: i am sorry,i try elaborate it ,thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,my question maybe unclear,by the view i can a one route to find all view ,resource :

```
Route::get('/{pac}/{menthod}',function($pac,$method){
$url = $pac . "." . $method;
return view($url);
});
```

but the controller

i try

```
//this is error
Route::match(['get','post'],'Controoler/{Controller}/{method}',$Controller ."@". $method);
```

or

```
//but the return a string to view  
Route::match(['get','post'].'{Controller}/{method}',function($Controller,$method){
    $url = $controller . "@" . $method;
    return $url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are searching for this

```
Route::get("/my/path", "MyController@myMethod");
Route::post("/my/path", "MyController@myMethod");
```

Or you can use this
[Route::resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)

Comment: yes,but the way only can route a one controller,i think a one controller will find all package class

Comment: then use Route::resource

Comment: OK ,thank you ,i successed, my way is          Route::resource('User','User_Controller');