# Best design practice to implement routes and controllers for a RESTFul Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel-5, restful-url

I am developing an application with Laravel 5.2, it has to be implemented RESTFUL. It is also very easy to implement RESTful resources in  Laravel. for example for getting all categories in `json` format in `routes` we just have to add

`Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');`

and then in the `CategoryController` we are going to have this for returning a `JSON` object of all categories:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller


public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();        

    return view('category.index', 
                ['categories' => $categories]);       
}
```

the the `mydomain.com\category` will be mapped to the above function automatically

The mobile applications and web application all have to deal with an uniform interface. it is obvious that mobile app(s) will send the request to the above URl (ourdomain.com/category) and then they will parse the `JSON` and display. but when it comes to web application I am getting a bit confused about how to implement the `routes` and their correspondent functions in the `Controllers` can I create the new functions in any format that I like?

for example: for displaying the categories in a web page is it recommended to create a new function in the same controller and call it for example `displayAll`

```
 public function displayAll()
{
    $categories = Category::all();        

    return view('category.index', 
                ['categories' => $categories]);       
}
```

and adding a route like

`Route::get('category/all', 'CategoryController@displayAll()')`

to the `routes` file? or is there any specific convention to obey or  is it a good practice to add those functions to the same `Controller` or create a new Controller?

Comment: http://apigee.com/about/resources/webcasts/restful-api-design-second-edition

Comment: could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller