# What is best practice in a Restful laravel app for Controllers and methods

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-5, restful-url

I am developing a restful laravel application and I need to know what is the best practice to implement the routes, controllers and methods in the Laravel to both support the `restful requests` and `HTTP web requests` we can easily create a resource controller and then add the following line to the routes file in Laravel:

`Route::resource('Photo', 'PhotoController');`

and then in the `PhotoController` we just need to add the following lines of codes which returns a `json` response from all the photos:

```
class PhotoController {

  public function index()
  {
     $photos = Photo::all();        

     return response()->
                        json(['result' => $photos]);       
     }
}
```

we also need a `Controller` and a `method` which responds to web `HTTP` request and returns a web page instead of a `json` response which displays all the photos to the web users

**Question:**
where is the best place to put this method and Controller is it a good practice to put it inside the same Controller and returns a view? like following example

```
class PhotoController{

 public function getAll(){
            $photos = Photo::getAll();

            return view('views',['photos'=>$photos]);
  }
}
```

or creating another `Controller` and handling the web requests there and adding a new `rout` in the `routes` file for example : `mysite.com\photos\all` to the routes file?

or do I have to keep this in another `Controller` or do I have to decide whether or not the request is from the web inside the same method like the below example:

```
 public function index()
{
   $photos = Photo::all();        
   if ( from web ){
      return view('views',['photos'=>$photos]);
   } else {
      return response()->
                    json(['result' => $photos]);   
   }

}
```

I also have to mention that I previously asked the below question:
[Best design practice to implement routes and controllers for a RESTFul Laravel app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695419/best-design-practice-to-implement-routes-and-controllers-for-a-restful-laravel-a) 
but didn't get any answer.

Comment: You probably want to check if request is ajax or request wants json response. Did you try using `if ($request->wantsJson()) {`?

Comment: I think they are many solutions and it all depends on what your project is. I like to have 2 sets of controllers, middleware, error handlers and to put all my logic in common service classes

Answer (score 6):

There's probably a reason why you didn't get an answer the last time you asked that question. It really depends on your project. I will share my own preference:

I have two sets of routes, middleware, controllers and common services.

**Routes:**

```
//For web
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');

/For API, with versioning 
Route::resource('api/v1/photo', 'API\PhotoController');
```

**Middlewares**

```
//For web
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role="view")
{
 if(Gate::denies($role.'-photo', $photo)){

        if($role == "view"){
            abort(404);
        }

        return $this->redirect($photo)->withErrors(['You are not authorized to see this photo']);;

    }
}
return $next($request);

/For API, with versioning 
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role="view")
{
   if(Gate::forUser(Auth::guard('api')->user())->denies($role.'-photo', $photo)){

        if($role == "view"){
            return Response::json([], 404);
        }

        return Response::json([], 403);

    }
}

return $next($request);
```

**Controllers**

```
//PhotoController
class PhotoController{

     //RESTful name here   
     public function index(){

         $photoService = new PhotoService();
         $photos = $photoService->getAll();

         return view('views',['photos'=>$photos]);
     }
}

//API\PhotoController
class PhotoController{

     //RESTful name here   
     public function index(){
         $photoService = new PhotoService();
         $photos = $photoService->getAll();

         return Response::json($photos, 200);
     }
}
```

**Service**

```
class PhotoService(){

    //You could add a _construct() that would accept Request $request or User $user

    public function getAll(){
        return Photo::all(); 
    }
}
```

**Bonus: Exception Handler**

You should take a look at this [RestExceptionHandlerTrait](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/best-way-to-handle-rest-api-errors-throwed-from-controller-or-exception).

It may seems like a lot of duplication but to me this is much more readable and clear than adding `$request->wantsJson()` everywhere. You might think that this is an overkill and, in some cases, it is probably an overkill.

However, I like this because the request and response logic from my api and my web are separated. Therefore I can deal with the different requests (ex: accessing the user information) and the different responses (ex: JSON or view). It also creates dedicated space for each type of request which allow you to execute extra logic if needed for each part of your app.

Again, it's a question of preference and project but I hope it answers your question.

Comment: @Siavosh My pleasure. Please accept if that answers your question