# Should all controllers have only the basic CRUD methods?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In Laravel, are **all** controllers only supposed to have the basic CRUD methods, as shown in the link below?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

That is, should the only methods in a controller be:

1. index()
2. create()
3. store()
4. show()
5. edit()
6. update()
7. destroy()

Thanks.

Comment: Not, it's not. It depends on your (app's) need and you can create any method if you want. The link is about a particular type of  Laravel's) controller and you can break the rules if you want. Probably, do some more research.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller

Answer (score 1):

No.

A controller can have methods named however you want!
If you are creating a RESTful controller, then the names of the methods make sense.

When you create a Resource Controller, then Laravel will save you the pain of writing the routes (you can use `Route::resource`)

For example: you can do this in `YourController.php`

```
function tada() {
return "Tadaaaa";
}
```

and then in your `routes.php`, you define a route like

```
Route::get('tada', 'YourController@tada');
```

And visiting that route will present you with the string `Tadaaaa`

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

No, You can have your own functions too. This is just a boilerplate that Laravel provides you to start with.