# Form action not correctly triggered in PHP Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I am using the Forms provided by Laravel Collective and it is correctly installed.
What I'm trying to do is to validate the Form in `PictureController.php`
Just like this:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Picture;
use DB;

class PictureController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pictures = Picture::all();
        return view('welcome')->with('pictures', $pictures);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pictures.publicize');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'hashtag' => 'required',
        ]);
        return 123;
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And this is the code snippet of `publicize.blade.php` which contains this form.

```html
{!! Form::open(array(
                                    'action' => 'PictureController@store',
                                    'method' => 'POST',
                                    'files' => true
                                  ))
                                !!}
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ Form::label('hashtag', 'HashTag') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('hashtag', '', ['placeholder' => 'Eg. #Happiness', 'class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'hashtag' /*'required'*/]) }}
                                  </div>
                                    {{ Form::submit('Publicize', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And in the `routes/web.php`, this is the code written...

```html
Route::resource('/', 'PictureController');
```

I have also submitted whole code on GitHub. Just look at [this commit](https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/myTaswir/tree/e3209c3983addb501d9d291f4560560b42850c77) to take a look at all the files.

**The problem is..**
When I look into the Source Code in browser, I see that `action` attribute in the form equals the home url, i.e `/public/`. It looks like the form is not connected to the controller and method I specified in `publicize.blade.php`. How can I make that form work properly with validations?

**Thanks for help in advance.**

Comment: @MayankMajithya Not completely, when I set the routes to picture, it worked. But what if I want to be at home page?

Comment: I had update answer, please check it may helps you

Answer (score 0):

update route, `web.php` ( you should try this way )

```
Route::resource('/', 'PictureController');
```

update action attribute also,

```
{!! Form::open(array(
        'action' => '/',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'files' => true
      ))
!!}
```

Source : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name in route,
For example :

```
Route::resource('picture', 'PictureController');
```

And set on your blade  like this,

```
{!! Form::open(array(
                     'action' => 'picture',
                     'method' => 'POST',
                     'files' => true
              ))
!!}
```