# Route not[discussion] defined

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route.

```
 Route::get('discussion/{slug}',[
    'use' => 'DiscussionsController@show',
    'as' => 'discussion.show'
]);
```

This is show function

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $discussion = Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('discussions.show', compact('discussion'));
}
```

i am getting this error.

view file like this

```
@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">{{$discussion->tittle}}</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

here i call redirect the route, and get the error

```
$discussion = Discussion::create([
        'tittle' => $request->title,
        'content' => $request->contant,
        'chanel_id' => $request->channel_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'slug' => str_slug($request->title)
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('discussion', ['slug' => $discussion->slug]);
```

**ERR_MSG**:

[image: error]

Comment: there is nothing here trying to generate a link to that route ... there is a stack trace that tells you where the error comes from

Comment: Maybe problem in here: you defined your route as discussion.show and calling it like discussion. Please provide us more information

Answer (score 0):

**Route**

```
Route::get('discussion/{slug}',['as'=>'discussion.show','use'=>'DiscussionsController@show']);
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($slug){

   $discussion = Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first();

   return view('discuss', compact('discussion'));
}
```

Your blade file must be discuss.blade.php

You are going to use that discussion.show if you only need something like this on your view page 
`<a href="{{route('discussion.show',['slug'=>$discuss->slug])}}">View Slug</a>`

Comment: It might be on your view blade. Can you update it with your blade file?

Comment: how can i do the same thing with resource route? 
 Route::resource('discussion', 'DiscussionsController');

Comment: Sorry If I'am being rude but you can try this link and you can find your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller

Comment: @SSarker Accept this as an answer if you think this answers your question

Comment: i create database with tittle :(

Comment: I have got my solution. Thank you for your help @christian