# Laravel 5.8 POST request always throws welcome page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test my API using postman, but when I hit the `POST` request, it's always throws me to the welcome page. I already set the XSRF token inside but still not working.

This is my `api.php` routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::resource('products/{product}/feedbacks', 'FeedbackController');
```

This is my store method from `FeedbackController`:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreFeedback  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Product $product, StoreFeedback $request)
{
   $product->addFeedback(
      $request->validated()
   );

   return response()->json([
      "status" => "success",
      "message" => "Your feedback has been submitted."
   ], 200);
}
```

Here is my `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('product-categories', 'ProductCategoryController')->parameters([
    'product_category' => 'productCategory'
]);

Route::resource('product-sub-categories', 'ProductSubCategoryController')->parameters([
    'product_sub_category' => 'productCategory'
]);
```

And here is the screenshot of my postman request: [Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu4GW.jpg)

Comment: Call you please show me your ```index()``` function ? What she returns?

Comment: please can you try to reverse the args in the `store()` function, i.e.: `store(StoreFeedback $request, Product $product)`

Comment: here, I uploaded it for you to see all my code: [link to code screenshot](https://imgur.com/c63vfrC). As you can see, it does not even touch the index method.

Comment: @dparoli Already tried that, still the same

Comment: what does your `web.php` file look like?  Any chance you have a `/api` route defined in there?

Comment: @BizzyBob I updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### POST request always throws the welcome page

**The problem lies in your `App\Http\Requests\StoreFeedback` class.**

#### How?

Cause you're passing the request through the Form Validator. Which invalidates the form request. And that's why passing the request back to the previous URL which becomes the `/` by default.

#### Hierarchy below

- [Invalidates the form](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L183)
- [Finds the previous URL](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L140)
- [Url Resolver](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L153)

But, if you want to get the errors, you can simply pass the HEADER `Accept:application/json` to request HEADER and you'll get the errors.

Reason: [ValidationException handled here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L183)

Comment: I was just about to post this!  from the docs `If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location.` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Comment: Since last year, I have been exploring laravel codes. That's unfolding my eyes. :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I missed an important part of validation

Answer (score 1):

I think It's showing the same page because you're using the `Route::resource`, as said in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller),

A RESTful resource controller sets up some default routes for you and even names them.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Gives you these named routes:

```
Verb          Path                        Action  Route Name
GET           /users                      index   users.index
GET           /users/create               create  users.create
POST          /users                      store   users.store
GET           /users/{user}               show    users.show
GET           /users/{user}/edit          edit    users.edit
PUT|PATCH     /users/{user}               update  users.update
DELETE        /users/{user}               destroy users.destroy
```

My guess is: you're basically calling the `index()` function in your FeedbackController over and over again

Change your route to:

```
Route::post('products/{product}/feedbacks', 'FeedbackController@store');
```

**EDIT** change your controller function to:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   dd($request->body); // or the key you send it on the postman
}
```

And show us what you got

Comment: U'uh.. it throws me to the index method instead of store :/

Comment: i forgot to point the function, its: 'FeedbackController@store'. I updated my answer. Try again

Comment: I know, I added a `return $request;` too on the controller, and still, nothing happen.. But when I change it to GET, it got fired :/ [link to the screenshot](https://imgur.com/9dB6HMO)

Comment: This is really strange, put a ```dd($request)``` and see what you got

Comment: It works when I do like this: `Route::post('products/{product}/feedbacks', function () { dd("It does work"); });`

Comment: You're getting the parameters you're sending?

Comment: yes, I got the parameters. but only if I hardcode it inside a function like this: [link to screenshot](https://imgur.com/f0ae1jB)

Comment: have you tried any other route (a teste route for example)? This seems like a connection problem, the route never reachs the function. Maybe try to receive just one parameter and print them, just to make sure the route is going to the right place. i Will update my anwser.

Comment: Yes, I did a GET request for it, it reaches the controller and the index method. It's also shows the Product data which is passed from the wildcard. It's weird :/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his code. The problem here is that the form validation failed and he's sent back to the previous page. As he is trying from the postman, there is no previous page, he is sent back to the home page or `/` by default. Don't suggest wrong things. If he passes the `Request` class, that will work. but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just found the problem, it was from the `app\Http\Requests\StoreFeedback` **like Mr.ssi-anik said**. I don't know why for the boolean validation, when I put `true` or `false`, it fails and redirect me to the welcome page.

Instead, I used `0` or `1`, it accepts the parameters and working normally.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above this is happening because of the form validator, You can also fix this using middlewares, first create a middleware:

```sh
php artisan make:middleware JsonRequestMiddleware
```

Update the handle method of your middleware

```php
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set("Accept", "application/json");
        return $next($request);
    }
```

then add this middleware to `app/Http/Kernel`

```php
protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\JsonRequestMiddleware::class,
       ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but it was my fault. I didn't add the right headers.

Make sure you specify "Content-Type" and "Accept". Both should be set to "application/json". See image below.

Hope this helps.

[Postman Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCRV7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution, add failedValidation function in Request

```
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        'success'   => false,
        'message'   => 'Validation errors',
        'data'      => $validator->errors()
    ]));
}
```