# how to display search result in laravel

Tags: laravel

i can not show search result using laravel. below is the code for route, controller and views:

route:

```
Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
```

controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;
use Redirect;
use Auth;
use DB;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $order = Order::all();
        return view(search.index', compact(search));
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->search;

        $order = DB::table('order')
            ->where('custName','like',"%".$search."%");

        return view('search.index',compact('search'));
    }
}
```

view

```
<form action="search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="custName" class="form-control" <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered" width="500">
            <tr>
                <td><font color="white">RESULT :</font></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach($order as $order)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $order->custName }}</td>
                <td>{{ $order->orderStatus }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```

directory location

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/web/resources/views/search/index.blade.php
```

show error

```
Undefined variable: order (View: c:\xampp\htdocs\web\resources\views\search\index.blade.php)
```

above is my code to search record in the database. but the result always undefined variable.

how to display the searched result using code above. thank you

Comment: pass `$order` to `view`, change this line `return view(search.index', compact(search));` to `return view(search.index', compact('order'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Controller search method, assign search result to **$orders**

```
$orders = DB::table('order')
            ->where('custName','like',"%".$search."%");
```

then send it to the view:

```
 return view('search.index',compact('orders'));
```

and in the view do this:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $order->custName }}</td>
      <td>{{ $order->orderStatus }}</td>
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: it show all records, not certain/particular name. what im try to do is. when user type "maxwell" the result show "maxwell" not all records. pls point me how to do it in laravel

Comment: @mogleng, What do you mean by 'it show all records, not certain/particular name' and 'show "maxwell" not all records'? Your search query is "%".$search."%" i.e. it would return all those rows which has 'maxwell' in the 'custName' column's value no matter where it is, even in the middle of a word. Ex: maxwell, Mr.maxwell, maxwellmyName

Comment: for instance i have a
aa
aaa
b
c
d

mr d

Comment: @mogleng, If you still face problem, you can post screenshot of your output

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the code you have shared, I try to tell the ones I see.

1. there is a misspelling in Route::resource where instead of **search** you coded **seearch**
2. as for search method it is not used anywhere by the route you provided. You can see more details on Route::resource for methods and views at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)
3. now considering that you are loading **index.blade.php** from the **public function index** method, the usage of compact is troubled. [At this page](https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/passing-multiple-variables-into-a-laravel-5-view/), you can see how compact and with are different and how to use it. The main problem here is that you are not actually passing the order to your view at all.
4. The last but not least, it is good practice to name items having a collection of values plurally. For example here the **order** should change to **orders**. This would prevent the misuse of it in foreach. In your foreach, the name of the iterating array and the temp variable keeping the data should be different, or otherwise, they would have conflict. **Here you have 2 variables called order in the same scope**.

Answer (score 0):

for instance i have records :

1. a
2. aa
3. aaa
4. b
5. c
6. d
7. e

the code show all record no1 until no7.
but now its solved i fixed the code in my controller in index() section as below

```
 public function index()
 {
        return view('search.index', compact('order'));
 }

 public function search(Request $request)
 {
        $search = $request->search;
        $order = DB::table('order')->where('custName', 'like', "%".$search."%")->get();

        return view('search.result', compact('order'));
    }
```