# student/create route shows blank page ,not displaying the insert form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

q)  i want to insert a form in la-ravel ,and my version is P hp 7 and la ravel 5.8. I write all codes  and run but it not showing the form or anything ,it shows blank page, and migration db and table also created ,but i cant insert ,because form is not displaying in the URL .. This is the URL `HTTP://localhost:8000/student/create`
    can u please help me?

1)   I tried `HTTP://localhost:8000/student/create`
    but it is not working

this is the view file ,`resources/views/student/create.blade.php`

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br />
        <h3 align="center">add data</h3>
        <br />

        @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>

                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                    @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
        @if(\Session::has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ \Session::get('success')}}</p>
        </div>
        @endif

        <form method="post" action="{{url('student')}}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control"
                 placeholder="enter the first name" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control"
                 placeholder="enter the last name" />
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

2)  this is controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\student;
use Session;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('student.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' =>  'required'
            ]);
        $student=new student([
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name'  => $request->get('last_name')
            ]);
        $student->save();
        return redirect()->route('student.create')->with('success','data added');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

3) this is the routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/first', function () {
    return view('first');
});


Route::get('/user', function () {
    return view('user');
});


Route::get('/{name}', function ($name) {
    return $name;
});


Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name="default brace") {
    return $name;
});
//Route::redirect("/Home","/user");


Route::get('/site{site}','youtube@index');

//Route::get("/site","youtube@index");


Route::resource('student/create','StudentController');





output its shows nothing ,only blank page only..
```

Comment: Please  add   this <form method="post" action="{{url('/student/create')}}">.  And also please edit your routes/web.php   
     Route::resource('student','StudentController');

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions that have the same problem in them. Clarify why this question is different from the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
Route::resource('student/create','StudentController');
```

to this:

```
Route::resource('students','StudentController');
```

and visit this address:

```
localhost:8000/students/create
```

See the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers).

There is also a typo in your `master.blade.php`, it must be `@yield('content')` (notice the place of `i` and `e`).

And in your view change the form tag like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('students.store')}}">
```

Comment: i tried,but form is not coming.  it shows @yeild('content'). thats only

Comment: Can you add the `master.blade.php` code to your question?

Comment: master.blade.php

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <title>Laravel CRUD</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  @yeild('content')
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Check the updated answer. It must be `yield` not `yeild`.

Comment: ok thank you,now it showing form but after submitting , showing 404|notfond and not inserting datas in table

Comment: here also i should use 'students' knw in action, action="{{url('/student/create')}}">

Comment: Check my answer again.  have named route with plural form `students` so if you are using my suggested code, you must use `action="{{url('/students/create')}}`

Comment: ok..after submitting shows like this... Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Resource route. It has index, create, store, show, edit, update and delete route. When you are using 127.0.0.1:8000/student/create it goes to your controller's index method and as you have nothing in your index method you are getting a blank page. So change your route like

```
Route::resource('student','StudentController');
```

Now you will able to visit the page

```
127.0.0.1:8000/student/create
```

And change your form action to

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('student.store')}}">
```

Comment: my bad, i have used `students` in defining route. it should be `student`

Comment: @linda you have misspelled `yield` in your master blade. it's `yield` and not `yeild`.

Comment: ok thank you,now it showing form but after submitting , showing 404|notfond and not inserting datas in table

Comment: have you changed your form action like i said in my answer?

Comment: Route [student.create] not defined.

Comment: not `student.create`. it should be `student.store` in form action.

Comment: that one only i give,error is Route [student.create]

Comment: where are you calling `student.create` route?

Comment: public function create()
    {
        return view('student.create');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please  add   this

And also please edit your routes/web.php
     Route::resource('student','StudentController');

For more detail please visit this link 
       [Laravel - Route::resource vs Route::controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You defined your student route resource wrong. You currently have it like this:

```
Route::resource('student/create','StudentController');
```

So when you check you `php artisan route:list`, you get the following output:

```
| GET|HEAD  | student/create/create        | create.create    | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@create
```

As you can see, you have create two times in your route name, and you are trying to find `student/create`

Change your route resource to this:

```
Route::resource('students','StudentController');
```

Now, when you go to `php artisan route:list` your route will look like this:

```
| GET|HEAD  | student/create         | student.create   | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@create
```

Now you will be able to call that route by going to `student/create` which will show your form.