# Laravel 7.x name routes in routes group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-route

I'm learning Laravel and I wanna group some routes using *prefix* and naming each route so I got something like this

```php
Route::prefix('customers')->group(
    function(){
        Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@index')->name('customers.index');
        Route::get('/create', 'CustomerController@create')->name('customers.create');
        Route::post('/', 'CustomerController@store')->name('customers.store');
});
```

I want to avoid writing **'customers.'** in every route name.

I have tried with *group* and *name* but it doesn't recognize the route name prefix **'customers.'**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customers', 'name' => 'customers.'],
    function(){
        Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@index')->name('index');
        Route::get('/create', 'CustomerController@create')->name('create');
        Route::post('/', 'CustomerController@store')->name('store');
});
```

The other way I found was with *as* and *use* but it seems to much code, and doesn't look kind of clean, actually the first one looks like a cleaner way.

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'customers',
    'as' => 'customers.'
    ],
    function(){
        Route::get('/', ['as'=>'index', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@index']);
        Route::get('/create', ['as'=>'create', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@create']);
        Route::post('/', ['as'=>'store', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@store']);
});
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RESTful Resource controller**

A RESTful resource controller sets up some default routes for you and even names them.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Gives you these named routes:

```
Verb          Path                        Action  Route Name
GET           /users                      index   users.index
GET           /users/create               create  users.create
POST          /users                      store   users.store
GET           /users/{user}               show    users.show
GET           /users/{user}/edit          edit    users.edit
PUT|PATCH     /users/{user}               update  users.update
DELETE        /users/{user}               destroy users.destroy
```

And you would set up your controller something like this (actions = methods)

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {}

    public function show($id) {}

    public function store() {}

}
```

You can also choose what actions are included or excluded like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', [
    'only' => ['index', 'show']
]);

Route::resource('monkeys', 'MonkeysController', [
    'except' => ['edit', 'create']
]);
```

Taken from [Laravel - Route::resource vs Route::controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `->name(XYZ)` when grouping:

```
Route::prefix('customers')
->name('customers.')
->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/create', 'CustomerController@create')->name('create');
    Route::post('/', 'CustomerController@store')->name('store');
});
```

Routes:

```
|        | POST     | customers              | customers.store  | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@store                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | customers              | customers.index  | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@index                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | customers/create       | customers.create | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@create                         | web        |
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)?

You would simply do the following to get your desired result with one line:

```php
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
```

Routes:

```
+----------+-------------------------------+
| Method   | URI                           |
+----------+-------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD | customers                     |
| POST     | customers                     |
| GET|HEAD | customers/create              |
+----------+-------------------------------+
```