# Ways to write Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Is there a better way to write these routes? It seems I am repeating the same controller in my route files.

```
Route::post('user', [UserController::class, 'update']);
Route::get('user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
Route::delete('users/{id}',[UserController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Comment: One way is use Resource controller. and then use resource routes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a resource route, where you specify a [subset of actions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes) in the controller.

```
Route::resource('user', UserController::class)->only([
    'index', 'update', 'destroy'
]);
```

You can also use the `--model` option when generating a controller with the stubbed out CRUD methods.

```
php artisan make:controller UserController --resource --model=User
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
| Method    | URI         | Name         | Action                                      | Middleware |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
| GET|HEAD  | user        | user.index   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index   | web        |
| PUT|PATCH | user/{user} | user.update  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update  | web        |
| DELETE    | user/{user} | user.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy | web        |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
```