# how to call delete route with ajax in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i want to call route resource with ajax, when i put type as delete i got error (exception   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException")
and given message (message  "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.").function almost work beacuse after make refresh the status also change but i am the above error.

route :

```
        Route::resource('category', ArtistCategoryController::class);
```

controller :

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = ArtistCategory::findOrFail($id);
    $deleteResponse = $category->update([
       'status'=>'d'
    ]);
    if ($deleteResponse) {
        deleteMessage();
        return redirect()->back();
    } else
        errorMessage();

}
```

view :

```
 <a href="" class="categoryDelete" data-id={{ $category->id}} ><i class="far fa-trash-alt" style="color: #b21f2d"></i></a>
```

ajax:

```
<script>
    $(".categoryDelete").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id = $(this).data('id')
        // console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/artist/category/'+id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            data:{"id": id, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function (e){
                alert(e)
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Route::resource vs Route::controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)

Answer (score 1):

solved it with some changes in destroy method
because i have used return `return  redirect()->back();`it gives error and this is unacceptable

updated

```
   public function destroy($id): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    $category = ArtistCategory::findOrFail($id);
    $deleteResponse = $category->update([
       'status'=>'d'
    ]);
    if ($deleteResponse) {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => [
                'id' => $id
            ],
            'status' => 'success',
        ]);
    } else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => [
                'id' => $id
            ],
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => __("Couldn't Delete. Please Try Again!")
        ], 500);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the csrf token in the header. Have a look at the docs in the bottom of the page: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Create a meta tag with the token like this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And grap it like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token()}}"/>
i have set meta tag in extend page