# how to display data based on specific id in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel. I want to send data as id of existing data. Id comes from products.blade I send via href tag as shown below to gallery page. I have tried to find a way through other sites but it still doesn't work

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/dashboard/galleries/{{ $product->id }}"><i class="ri-image-add-line text-white"></i></a>
```

then i create a route like this

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/galleries', DashboardGalleryController::class)->middleware('admin')->shallow();
```

in the controller gallery, I made like this

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::where('products_id', $id)->get();
        return view('dashboard.galleries.index', compact('gallery'));
    
    }
```

then inside the gallery page, I want to display a table to add images based on that id.

dashboard/galleries/index.blade.php

```
<h1>{{ $gallery->id }}</h1>
```

should i add data inside foreach or outside?

Comment: `$product = [...] $product->id`? That is never going to work. Should be `$product = Gallery::where('products_id', $id)->get();` (notice `$id` in `index($id)`? Also, `$product` is a terrible name for a Collection of `Gallery` records; should be `$galleries`, or similar (plural, since `->get()` returns Many, and because it's not a `Product`)

Comment: hello @TimLewis, thanks for responding to my question. I've tried changing it but still nothing happens. In the gallery view, it only displays blank and no error messages at all

Comment: You didn't include the code for `dashboard/galleries/index.blade.php`, so until you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74549637/edit) and include that code, there is no way for us to help you further.

Comment: I've added the blade view, the rest of it looks just normal bootstrap like a table

Comment: Yeah, `$gallery->id` is not going to work; you have **multiple** `Gallery` instances returned by `->get()`, how is your code supposed to know which `->id` to reference? This is why I suggested you use `$galleries`, so you can do `$galleries = Gallery::where('products_id', $id)->get()`, then `return view('dashboard.galleries.index', compact('galleries'));`, then `@foreach($galleries as $gallery)`, then `{{ $gallery->id }}` will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A restful resource controller sets up some default routes for you and even names them.
and ur case the logic should be inside `show()` function not `index()`

check this issue it will help u [same issue solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)