# 405 Method Not Allowed (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello Good Day to anyone who would see this, I am new to Laravel and currently having a minor problem that for some reason every time I delete, it would show the 405 (Method Not Allowed) in the console. The reason I considered it a minor problem since it works anyways when I refresh it.

I'm sorry if I'm bad at explaining but here's some screenshots to hopefully clarify the situation

[Error Message Triggered when I press Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOrJD.png)

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD6WW.png)

But note that when I refresh it actually deletes that record...

I would post what I think are the relevant codes here :<

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Waste;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WasteController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $waste = Waste::all();
        return view('wastes.index', compact('waste'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('wastes.create');
    }    

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the request
        $request->validate([
            'WasteID' => 'required|unique:wastes', 
            'WasteName' => 'required',
            
        ]);

        // Create
        Waste::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('wastes.index')->with('success', 'Waste record created successfully!');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $waste = Waste::findOrFail($id);
        return view('wastes.show', compact('waste'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $waste = Waste::findOrFail($id);
        return view('wastes.edit', compact('waste'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Validate
        $request->validate([
            'WasteID' => 'required|unique:wastes,WasteID,' . $id, 
            'WasteName' => 'required',
            
        ]);

        // Update
        $waste = Waste::findOrFail($id);
        $waste->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('wastes.index')->with('success', 'Waste record updated successfully!');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $waste = Waste::findOrFail($id);
        $waste->delete();

        return redirect()->route('wastes.index')->with('success', 'Waste record deleted successfully!');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\WasteController;

Route::get('/wastes', [WasteController::class, 'index'])->name('wastes.index');
Route::get('/wastes/create', [WasteController::class, 'create'])->name('wastes.create');
Route::resource('wastes', WasteController::class);
Route::delete('/wastes/delete-selected', [WasteController::class, 'deleteSelected'])->name('wastes.deleteSelected');
Route::delete('/wastes/{waste}', [WasteController::class, 'destroy'])->name('wastes.destroy');
```

View using it:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Waste Records</h1>

    @if(session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="mb-3">
        <a href="{{ route('wastes.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Waste Record</a>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteSelected()">Delete Selected</button>
    </div>

    <table class="table" id="wasteTable">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sort="WasteID">Select</th>
                <th data-sort="WasteID">Waste ID</th>
                <th data-sort="WasteName">Waste Name</th>
                <th data-sort="WasteType">Waste Type</th>
                <th data-sort="TimeCollected">Time Collected</th>
                <th data-sort="MassCollected">Mass Collected</th>
                <th data-sort="AreaCollected">Area Collected</th>
                <th data-sort="DisposalLocation">Disposal Location</th>
                <th data-sort="WasteCategory">Waste Category</th>
                <th>Other Description</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @forelse($waste as $record)
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="{{ $record->id }}"></td>
                    <td>{{ $record->WasteID }}</td>
                    <td contenteditable="false" data-id="{{ $record->id }}" data-field="WasteName" class="editable">{{ $record->WasteName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->WasteType }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->TimeCollected }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->MassCollected }} kg</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->AreaCollected }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->DisposalLocation }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->WasteCategory }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->OtherDescription }}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($record->Solid) Solid, @endif
                        @if($record->Liquid) Liquid, @endif
                        @if($record->Biodegradable) Biodegradable, @endif
                        @if($record->NonBiodegradable) Non-Biodegradable, @endif
                        @if($record->Recyclable) Recyclable, @endif
                        @if($record->Hazardous) Hazardous, @endif
                        @if($record->Corrosive) Corrosive, @endif
                        @if($record->Ignitable) Ignitable, @endif
                        @if($record->Reactive) Reactive, @endif
                        @if($record->Toxic) Toxic, @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('wastes.show', $record->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('wastes.edit', $record->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteRecord({{ $record->id }})">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="12">No waste records found.</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {{-- Scripts Area --}}
    <script src="{{ asset('jquery-3.7.1.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
         var sortOrder = {};

         
        $('table th').on('click', function() {
            var column = $(this).data('sort');
            if (!sortOrder[column]) {
                sortOrder[column] = 'asc';
            } else {
                sortOrder[column] = sortOrder[column] === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
            }

            sortTable(column, sortOrder[column]);
        });

        
        function sortTable(column, order) {
            var rows = $('table tbody tr').get();

            rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                var keyA = $(a).children('td').eq(getColumnIndex(column)).text();
                var keyB = $(b).children('td').eq(getColumnIndex(column)).text();

                if (order === 'asc') {
                    return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : -1;
                } else {
                    return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : -1;
                }
            });

            $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
                $('table tbody').append(row);
            });
        }

        
        function getColumnIndex(columnName) {
            var index = -1;
            $('table th').each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).data('sort') === columnName) {
                    index = i;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return index;
        }

        
        function sortTable(column, order) {
            var rows = $('table tbody tr').get();

            rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                var keyA = $(a).children('td').eq(getColumnIndex(column)).text();
                var keyB = $(b).children('td').eq(getColumnIndex(column)).text();

                if (order === 'asc') {
                    return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : -1;
                } else {
                    return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : -1;
                }
            });

            $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
                $('table tbody').append(row);
            });
        }

        
        function getColumnIndex(columnName) {
            var index = -1;
            $('table th').each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).data('sort') === columnName) {
                    index = i;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return index;
        }

        //!!
        function deleteSelected() {
            var selectedIds = $('input[name="selected[]"]:checked').map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            if (selectedIds.length === 0) {
                alert('Please select at least one record to delete.');
                return;
            }

            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected records?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ route('wastes.deleteSelected') }}',
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        "selectedIds": selectedIds
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response.message);
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        alert('Error deleting selected records.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //!!
        function deleteRecord(WasteID) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/wastes/' + WasteID,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response.message);
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        alert('Error deleting the record.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#wasteTable').DataTable();
    });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: I think the first part of this answer could be of use to you. I think you need to choose between manually implementing the routes or using the `Route::resource('')` routes, seems they are conflicting. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23506685/9636400

Comment: sometimes the `WasteID` you pass into `deleteRecord` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The console image reveals that you're doing a `DELETE` request to `/wastes` which, per your routes configuration, doesn't exist.

You do have a resource URL that accept `DELETE` requests to `/wastes/{waste}`.

That's why you get a 405 on the request.

Comment: As a comment, you should really read up on routes in the documentation and split up your resource controllers from your view representation.

Answer (score 0):

in route file order is important.
first you wrote `get` than wrote `resource` and the end `delete`. its wrong.
and in my opinion you can use manual routing and change `delete` to `post` method.

otherwise if you want to use `delete` method you can

```
"_method":"delete"
```

to your ajax data and use `POST` method.

see more: [How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery#:%7E:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20make%20a%20%24.post%20work%20to%20a%20Laravel%20Route%3A%3Adelete%20or%20Route%3A%3Aput%20just%20add%20an%20argument%20%22_method%22%3D%22delete%22%20or%20%22_method%22%3D%22put%22.)

your ajax should be like this:

```
           $.ajax({
                    url: '/wastes/' + WasteID,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        "_method": "delete",
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response.message);
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        alert('Error deleting the record.');
                    }
                });
```